# Multiple conditions and selecting columns in r

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I set conditions that thin out a data frame of 258 obs of 50 variables:

```
reductionK <- data_frame[data_frame$distance>=2500 & data_frame$distance<=2900, ]
```

but I would also like in the same request to select only a few columns (not using subset)

It works for 1 column:

```
reductionK <- data_frame[data_frame$distance>=2500 & data_frame$distance<=2900, "redkm"]
```

How can I have more than one columns in reductionKM knowing the names of the columns to select? (for example's sake col1, col2, col27)

Comment: Like this `data_frame[data_frame$distance>=2500 & data_frame$distance<=2900, c("redkm" , "col1", "col2")]`

Comment: thank you for the proper syntax

Comment: as a complement for people who might want to leave out NA's from their results: reductionK<-na.omit(data_frame[data_frame$distance>=2500 & data_frame$distance<=2900, c("redkm","distance","nom_cheval")])